# webcrawler bots load test my website and it fails the test

Tags: tomcat, robots.txt

we run a commerical website with a relavitely few number of customer at any one time ~30 users .

Frequently a webcrawler such as google bot, bing bot, and 80legs will bring our site to a grinding halt. Altering robots.txt does not have an immediate effect. Is their anyway to stop 80legs instantly ? It is using different ip's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://wiki.80legs.com/w/page/1114616/FAQ#HowdoInbspslowdown008whencrawlingmysite

> How do I slow down 008 when crawling my site?
>
> The easiest solution is to contact us and let us know at what rate you would like us to throttle crawls on your site (in terms of requests/second).

Of course you can also check for the User-Agent and rate limit and/or block these requests completely.

Comment: yeah thanks but none of that is particularly fast, I have altered robots.tx tbut that is only picked up by them every 3hrs - we are getting the equivalent ddos attack

Comment: Blocking based on User-Agent would be instant

Comment: only if they pick it up instantly and actually obey the rules, which they don't apparently.

Comment: No, you tell your webserver to check for the User-Agent and block these requests. The only way to get around this for them is to change the User-Agent - this is possible, but a commercial provider will probably not do this

Comment: oh, how would I tell tomcat to block a user agent without using robots.txt, which relies on co-operation of the bot ?

Comment: and I can't block by Ip as 80legs uses over 50k different ones.

Comment: I don't know who to do that with Tomcat - from what I understand you need something like UrlRewriteFilter and setup a rule for this case

Comment: Yes you can, if you set the <to> to `null` (examples here, even based on User-Agent further down the page: http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/2.6/guide.html)

Comment: thanks I was just lookign at that, I think I will forward the requests to 80legs.com :-)